# append an field of mysql with cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, append

can someone help me with this cakephp code ?

i try to append a field in an UpdateAll...

```
$this->MyModel->updateAll(
array(
    'MyModel.Field1'     => ***MyModel.Field1 & 'ok'***,
),
array('MyModel.Field2' => 'lorem')
);
```

Comment: ps: sorry for my english ... but i think that anyone gonna understand the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the docs, the `$fields` argument of `Model::updateAll()` accepts SQL expressions, so just pass whatever is needed, in your case probably a `CONCAT` operation:

```
$this->MyModel->updateAll(
    array('MyModel.Field1' => "CONCAT(MyModel.Field1, 'ok')"),
    array('MyModel.Field2' => 'lorem')
);
```

And don't forget that the values are not being escaped! In case you are planning to inject user data, make sure that you prepare it properly using `DboSource::value()`. Unfortunately there is no way to bind parameters when using `updateAll()`, which should always be the method of choice to insert data when no automatic escaping is being applied.

See also **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions**